# get position of item in list view with custom GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, swipe, android-gesture

I have a custom list adapter that with ViewHolder pattern sets an OnTouchListener passing the event to my custom gesture listener extending SimpleOnGestureListener

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item_swipeable, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

//            holder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            holder.container = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);

            holder.created_at = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_created_at);
            holder.link = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_link);
            holder.origin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_origin);
            holder.mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(mContext, new MyGestureListener (mContext, convertView));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.created_at.setText( mData.get(position).getCreated_at());
        holder.link.setText( mData.get(position).getLink());
        holder.origin.setText( mData.get(position).getOrigin());


        holder.container.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                holder.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }
```

the gesture listener overrides OnFling in order to detect swipe on each row, make invisible the content and display instead some buttons.

```
public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final String TAG = "MyGestureListener";
    private RelativeLayout backLayout;
    private LinearLayout frontLayout;
    private Animation inFromRight,outToRight,outToLeft,inFromLeft;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams frontParams;
    private ViewGroup.LayoutParams backParams;

    public MyGestureListener(Context ctx, View convertView) {
        backLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_back);
        frontLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_front);
        inFromRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.in_from_right);
        outToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.out_to_right);
        outToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.out_to_left);
        inFromLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.in_from_left);    
    }  
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                           float velocityY) {
        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                if(diffX<0){
                    Log.v(TAG, "Swipe Right to Left");
                    if(backLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){

                        frontParams = frontLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        backParams = backLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        Log.d("HEIGHT FRONT ", ": "+frontParams.height ); // why -1?
                        Log.d("HEIGHT BACK ", ": "+backParams.height ); // why -1?

                        frontLayout.startAnimation(outToLeft);
                        backLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        backLayout.startAnimation(inFromRight);
                        frontLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.v(TAG, "Swipe Left to Right");
                    if(backLayout.getVisibility()!=View.GONE){
                        backLayout.startAnimation(outToRight);
                        backLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        frontLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        frontLayout.startAnimation(inFromLeft);
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
        return true;
    }    
}
```

unfortunately, in my main activity i was using a setOnItemClickListener over the list view itself in order to **get the position of the clicked element**, retrieve the corresponding object from my container (an Arraylist) and access to its id field which is crucial to query the database for deleting or updating it .

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //String p = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String link_id = linkList.get(position).getId();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "item clicked: "+position+"\n link id: "+link_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

this doesn't work anymore, and after looking at so many examples here on SO, my mind is completely shut down.
Please can you kindly explain how to get the position of the clicked element from my main activity with this particular setup?

Comment: use `AdapterView#getPositionForView` method, but honestly `RecyclerView` and `ItemTouchHelper` is by far better

Comment: Sorry I don't understand where and how should I use that method . In need the position of the clicked item so that upon click of a row I open its Details in a new activity . But the onTouchListener in my adapter intercepts everything .

Comment: Uhm, i can't find a way to use getPositionForView inside MyGestureListener. In the constructor i have convertView but can't call that method upon it. Sorry it's my first with a custom gesture listener i don't know how to use it. I chose ListView because it was in the first tutorial i found about getting jSon parsed with a custom Adapter (first time as well). If you say i can achieve swipe, click and jSon parsing with Recycler view as well, I might be willing to try it if you can guide me through